# Pipes do not connect to each other - geometric network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network, geometric-network, pipe-network

I have created a geometric network in ArcGIS for Desktop. Some of the pipes are not logically connecting to each other even though they appear to geometrically intersect.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

For example, I have used "Find connected" at the flag in the figure below. You can see that the pipe is geometrically connected to the intersecting pipe.

[image]

I have zoomed into the intersection as much as possible and they seem to be connected.

[image]

The figure below show the configuration of the geometric network and the feature dataset.

[image]

Comment: Split thin line in two at intersection. Read again what connection mean.

Comment: To add to what felix said... simple edges can only connect at endpoints. Complex edges would connect at vertex or endpoint. Either change the network definition or split all the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection needs to be exact: the end point of one line must touch another end point or a line. When you draw a new line, you should therefore activate the snapping environment to make sure that it is accurately located. If your lines already exist, you could use "[planarize line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-at-intersections-with-planarize.htm)" tool to split lines at each intersection so that they connect. But then you only correct overshoots, not undershoots, and you need to remove the small extra line segments. For undershoots, you could use the "[extend line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/extend-line.htm)" tool. Alternatively, it is possible to use the "[integrate](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm)" tool to move neighbor feature locations within a given tolerance, but this tool should be used carefully because it potentially modifies all vertices. Finally, for a large network, you should use the topology tools (rule must not have dangle), but this is more complex.

Comment: "Planarize line" solved the problem. Why is it necessary to use this tool to solve the problem? - can it be solved using tollerence value instead?